# grep for lines with semicolon in unix

Tags: unix

I am trying to get disk information from `fdisk -l` output on linux.

```
fdisk -l | grep -E 'Disk /dev/sd.\:'
```

I get the following output.

```
Disk /dev/sde doesn't contain a valid partition table
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
```

but what I want to get is

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
```

I tried to do this

```
fdisk -l | grep -E 'Disk /dev/sd.\:' | grep -v "contain"
```

but I have no idea why grep is not ignoring the line containing "contain".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command:

```
fdisk -l 2>/dev/null | grep -E 'Disk /dev/sd.\:'
```

OR simply:

```
fdisk -l 2>/dev/null
```

Problem is that the line `Disk /dev/sde doesn't contain a valid partition table` is being generated as error and being written on `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Pipe in unix only pipes output written on `stdout` from previous command with the command on RHS of pipe hence your grep command is only working on 2nd and 3rd line while 1st line on your terminal is coming from `stderr`.

Comment: I think it's better (less risky) to redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and deal with that combined output, rather than to `/dev/null` in case some other unexpected error condition occurs. With the former you'll see the error (depending on how you grep), but once all of `stderr` goes to `/dev/null` you'll never know if some other unexpected error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Your original grep doesn't work because the error message about "no valid partition" gets written to `stderr`. The solution is to *redirect* `stderr` to `stdout` and *then* grep it. Depending on the shell the command will vary.

E.g., csh/tcsh:

```
  fdisk -l |& grep -E 'Disk /dev/sd.\:' | grep -v "contain"
```

sh/bash:

```
  fdisk -l 2>&1 | grep -E 'Disk /dev/sd.\:' | grep -v "contain"
```

**NOTE**: Redirecting/suppressing all of `stderr` to `/dev/null` is dangerous as *all* error messages (expected and *not*) will go there. Much safer to combine `stderr` and `stdout` and deal with that stream selectively.

Answer (score 0):

All unix commands has two outputs; stderr and stdout. Errors are printed on stderr, and normal output on stdout. In your example, you can send stderr to /dev/null to get rid of the extra line. Like this:

`fdisk -l 2>/dev/null`